# Is vasectomy permissible in Islam?

Tags: medical, health

Is vasectomy permissible in Islam to prevent further pregnancies? If not then what are the ways acceptable under Islam to prevent unwanted pregnancies?

Answer (score -1):

AoA brothers and sisters, hope you are well.

The most commonly used (and agreed on) solution is usually birth control pills and condoms.

Hope this answer helped!

-Amber

Answer (score -2):

In the name of Allah, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful. The question of vasectomy or any form of contraception is a complex one.

As a principle, Islam encourages the propagation of the human race and views children as a blessing. However, it also recognizes the need for responsible family planning for the health and well-being of the mother, existing children, and the family as a whole.

Some people argue that permanent methods such as vasectomy are not permissible unless there's a serious health risk for the wife if she were to become pregnant again, as these methods alter the human body and prevent the possibility of future offspring.

However, a more liberal interpretation might allow for vasectomy in certain circumstances, especially if other methods of contraception are not suitable or effective, and if the decision is made with the intention of ensuring the welfare of the existing family members.

As for other methods of contraception, many scholars agree that methods such as birth control pills, IUDs, or condoms are permissible as long as they are used with mutual consent and for a legitimate purpose, such as protecting the health of the wife or ensuring the family's financial stability.